# Created tab always open the url in the same tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following `sample.js` for Google Chrome extension and I would like to know if there is a way that make it able to open url in the same tab every time:

```
function getword(info,tab) {    
    chrome.tabs.create({ 
        url: "http://translate.google.com/#en/ar/" + info.selectionText,
    })
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Translate: %s", 
    contexts:["selection"], 
    onclick: getword,

});
```

The extension send the selected text on the page to be translated on Google translate and I want every time the user uses it to open in the same Window's tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Us a variable to track if you have created a tab and once you have use [chrome.tabs.update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) to update it instead of opening a new one. I think users will find this experience confusing though since sometimes a new tab is opened and sometimes there isn't. You will also have to handle the error situation if the users has closed the tab you are trying to update.

```
var tabId = false;

if (tabId === false) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ 
        url: "http://translate.google.com/#en/ar/" + info.selectionText,
    }, function(tab) {
        tabId = tab.id;
    });
}  else {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { 
        url: "http://translate.google.com/#en/ar/" + info.selectionText,
    });
}
```

Comment: What I mean is something like target attribute of of `<a>`. So when we set this attribute value for all links in the page to the same value, they going to be opened in the same tab. Indeed, I don't want to leave the page that word found on it.

Comment: To add to this answer, one can keep track of the tab closing by listening to `chrome.tabs.onRemoved` and clearing `tabId` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement to avoid opening multiple tabs for the same URL.  I also employed tabs.query to check if a tab with the URL property matching the new tab was already open.  If so then I inform the user via a msg box with a 'yes' or 'no' button asking if he wants to open a new tab or over-write the current matching tab.  If 'yes' then I tabs.update the already open tab with the url of the newly created tab and close the new tab.  It is a bit cluggy but seems to work.  I initially found the tabs.query function confusing but eventually have grown to like it.

In the code below I am doing something slightly different.  I want to know if the browser has open a tab with the title of 'Agent Home'.  If yes then I update that tab after retrieving its tab.id with the tab.url of the newly created tab.  In a different scenario, I check if a tab containing "PAMM v4.0" in its title is open.  If so I pop a message box then either close the newly created tab.  I am in the process of opening the new tab but making it tabs.inactive.

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function funcName (tabs) {
    var tabID = 0;
    var tabURL = "";
    var tabTitle = "";
    var length = 0;
    var HomeOrV4 = "";


    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(T){
    length = T.length;
        if(length >0){
            for(var i = 0; i<T.length; i++){
            tabTitle = T[i].title;
            tabID = T[i].id;
            tabURL = T[i].url;
            if(tabTitle == "PAMM - Agent Home"){
                HomeOrV4 = "Home";
            return; 
            }
            if(tabTitle == "PAMM v4.0"){
                HomeOrV4 = "V4";
            return;
            }
        }
        }
    }); 
    });

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id, status){ 
    var V4tabID = 0;
    var V4TabURL = "";
    var AHPtabID = 0;
    if(status.status == "complete"){
            console.log("Tab loaded ");

chrome.tabs.query({title:"PAMM - Agent Home Page"}, function(Tabs){
    if(Tabs.length>1){
            Tabs.remove(Tabs[0].id);
    }
    if(Tabs.length = 1){
        AHPtabID = Tabs[0].id;
        //chrome.tabs.remove(V4tabID );                         
            }
    });     

chrome.tabs.query({title:"PAMM v4.0"}, function(Tabs){
    if(Tabs.length > 1){
        var r = confirm("You need to complete the open Guest Card. Press OK to continue   ...")
    if(r==true){
        chrome.tabs.update(Tabs[Tabs.length-1].id,{active:false});
       //chrome.tabs.remove(Tabs[Tabs.length-1].id);
       chrome.tabs.update(Tabs[0].id,{selected:true});
       }
        }

        if(Tabs.length == 1){
        tabID = Tabs[0].id;
        if (AHPtabID >0){
        chrome.tabs.remove(AHPtabID);
        }
    V4TabURL = Tabs[0].url;     }   
        });     

        }
    else{
        console.log("Tab loading");     
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to above answers, you need to add permission to access tabs in the `manifest` file, in case you want to access  `url`, `title`, or `favIconUrl` properties of `tabs`.

```
 "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs"],
```

Comment: False. It is not needed for `create`, no matter what properties you set. It's only about reading properties off existing tabs.

Comment: You can use most chrome.tabs methods and events without declaring any permissions in the extension's manifest file. However, if you require access to the url, title, or favIconUrl properties of tabs.Tab, you must declare the "tabs" permission in the manifest, as shown below:

Comment: That only applies to querying tabs. I double-checked right now. One can use `create`/`update` to modify the URL, the only thing you're not allowed is to read it for an existing tab.

Comment: In the above answers, they are accessing url and title for tabs. thats why I added. Without adding that "tabs" in permission I could not get the values.

Comment: **No, they are not.** Not the @abraham's answer. He is setting these properties and not querying them. @MikeReynolds' code does, but it's suboptimal here. It's much better to keep track of the tabId and not ask the _scary_ `"tabs"` permission.

Comment: But with Abrahams answer, if the user close an open tab ... what will happen. In my case, I query the tabs.url, i.e. MikeReynolds code seems a better solution. But my requirement is little different. However, do you know, how to highlight/focus the newly updated tab?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54132/discussion-between-xan-and-karim).